# $\mathbb{P}(|\xi|>t)\leq e^{-\alpha t}$ for $t>2$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\xi$ be a random variable such that $(\mathbb{E}|\xi|^p)^{1/p}\leq p$ for all $p\geq1$. Prove there is a positive constant $\alpha$ such that for all $t\geq2$, $\mathbb{P}(|\xi|>t)\leq e^{-\alpha t}$.

I've been using Chernoff's bound to get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|\xi|>t)&\leq e^{-\alpha t}\mathbb{E}(e^{\alpha|\xi|})\\
&=e^{-\alpha t}(1+\alpha\mathbb{E}|\xi|+\frac{\alpha^2}{2!}\mathbb{E}|\xi|^2+...).
\end{align*}
But from here I get stuck. I also don't know how to use the assumption on the $p$-norm, other than the idea that it can help simplify $\mathbb{E}e^{\alpha|\xi|}$.

Comment: What exactly is the assumption on the $p$-norm?

Comment: I edited it. That should help

Answer (score 1):

If what you've written so far is correct, then it is sufficient to choose $\alpha$ so small that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n n^n}{n!}$ is convergent. One can use the ratio test: the ratio is $\frac{\alpha (n+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{\alpha n^{n+1}(1+1/n)^{n+1}}{n^n (n+1)}=\frac{\alpha n (1+1/n)^{n+1}}{n+1}$. The limit of this is $\alpha e$, so you get convergence if $\alpha<1/e$. One could also have done this using Stirling's formula.